# Hiding legendbox title in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

How do we hide the title in legendbox and remove the padding on top.

```
const lb = chart.addLegendBox()
lb.setPosition({
  x: 50,
  y: 50
})

const entry = lb.add(series, undefined, 'Legend Box')
```

If I replace `'Legend Box'` above I get undefined group as title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no way to delete the title of LegendBox.

Some things you can try:

- Pass empty string ' ' instead of undefined
- Try negative paddings, margins
- Create your own LegendBox (make a Layout UIElement, add CheckBox elements to it, attach CheckBoxes to series using `series.attach`)

In v3.0.0 release (late this month), there will be proper API for LegendBox title.

EDIT

General syntax of creating Layout, CheckBox and attaching it to a series:

```
const customLegendBox = chart.addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column)
const entry1 = customLegendBox.addElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox)
mySeries.attach(entry1)
```

Comment: Hi , can we see any examples for attaching CheckBoxes to series using series.attach ?

Comment: Also , can we reduce the font size , colors of text in legenbox entries and chart titles ??